# Codeception connect external modules to tests on Yii2

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, functional-testing, codeception

We are moving the project to Yii2, codefile on yii2 is configured.
All configs of the web application and connection to the database are configured.

Simple functional tests work, for example:

```
$I->amOnRoute('site/login');
$I->see('Login', 'h1');
```

We changed the authorization method in YII itself, the external module Client_authorize is called in the afterLogin method.
Client_authorize is our old authorization module. The test refuses to see it, throws an exception "[Error] Class 'Client_authorize' not found".

If in the file "_bootstrap.php" write:

```
include ROOT. 'modules/authorize/client_authorize.php';
```

or

```
Autoload :: addNamespace('', '/vagrant/modules/authorize/');
Autoload :: load(Client_authorize::class);
```

Then, when the test is run, the contents of the file "client_authorize.php"

Comment: It looks like you missed the end of the last statement. What happens to contents of the file "client_authorize.php"?

Comment: The "codecept build" or "codecept run unit" command does not execute the file, but outputs its source code to the console

Comment: Have you missed <?php at the beginning of that file?

Comment: Yes, at the beginning of the file I have <?.
How do I set "short_open_tag = On" for the codeception?

Comment: Fix your code instead. but if you insist, run php with a custom php.ini file:  `php -c my-custom.ini vendor/bin/codecept run`  or enable it in your cli/php.ini file.

Comment: Thank you! We will correct the code.